# Why does maven download jar from spring repo?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have a mirror in settings.xml and pom.xml like this

settings.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>

    <pluginGroups>
    </pluginGroups>

    <proxies>
    </proxies>
    <servers>
      <server>
        <id>nexus-release</id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
      </server>

      <server>
        <id>nexus-snapshot</id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
      </server>
    </servers>

    <mirrors>
       <mirror>
        <id>nexus-any</id>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
        <name>Nexus any</name>
        <url>http://anyHost:2227/repository/maven-public</url>
      </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
    </profiles>
  </settings>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.my.projecy</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.3.0</version>

<modules>
    <module>my-project-pool</module>
    <module>my-project-business</module>
    <module>my-project-web-deploy</module>
    <module>my-project-task-deploy</module>
    <module>my-project-stats</module>
    <module>my-project-bizlog</module>
</modules>

<name>my-project</name>
<description>Educational Administration Offline System</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <mybatis.version>1.3.2</mybatis.version>
    <httpClient.version>4.5.5</httpClient.version>
    <maven.plugins.jar.version>3.1.0</maven.plugins.jar.version>
    <maven.plugins.assembly.version>3.1.0</maven.plugins.assembly.version>
    <offline.api.version>1.3.1-SNAPSHOT</offline.api.version>
    <online.api.version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</online.api.version>
    <starter.httpclient.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</starter.httpclient.version>
    <lombok.version>1.16.2</lombok.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.projecy.starter</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${starter.httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.projecy</groupId>
        <artifactId>bluesky-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.projecy</groupId>
        <artifactId>ea-api-online</artifactId>
        <version>${online.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${mybatis.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpClient.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.projecy</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-project-pool</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.projecy</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-project-business</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.projecy</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-project-web-deploy</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.projecy</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-project-task-deploy</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.projecy</groupId>
            <artifactId>ea-api-offline</artifactId>
            <version>${offline.api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.projecy</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-project-stats</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.projecy</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-project-bizlog</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.plugins.assembly.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

But when I try to compile my project, I get this error:

```
Could not find artifact com.my.package:httpclient-starter:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
in spring-snapshot (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot)
```

1. I tried to delete all folders under local repo or `mvn clean compile -U`
2. I tried grep "repo.spring.io" with settings.xml and pom.xml and got nothing
3. Only use single repo works for me.

Like this:

```
<mirror>
  <id>my-id</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <name>any name</name>
  <url>http://anyHost:2227/repository/maven-public</url>
</mirror>
```

How can I know why maven downloads this dependency from spring repo?

Comment: Without a pom file it's hard to say?

Comment: @khmarbaise More information is updated now.

Comment: try running mvn:dependency tree. Is it a transitive dependency?

Comment: The point is many of the spring--xxx pom's contain the definition for spring repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct `settings.xml` setup for using a repository manager should look like this:

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  <servers>
    <!-- Possible authentications for access to nexus -->
    <server>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <username>xxx</username>
      <password>xxx</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>releases</id>
      <username>xxx</username>
      <password>xxx</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

this will correctly redirect all request which are defined in your own or other pom's (like spring-boot repos) to your internal repository manager.

Comment: If I have a thirdparty dependency `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>`  this is not work for me. If I set it  `<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>`, with your settings.xml template , maven still downloads dependency from spring repo.

Comment: If you third party you should upload them to your repository manager and configure it in your repository manager ...and keep the `*` as I suggested..

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the part of Maven downloading from Spring's snapshot repository. From what you showed us in the question it is at least unclear (if not existent) that you defined any snapshot repository in your project. Because this is a Spring Boot project, it will set you one through the parent project (`..repo.spring.io..`).
This is why your project reaches out to this particular server.

You try to download a jar you probably put to nexus by yourself, right? The version is `<sth>-SNAPSHOT` that make Maven try to fetch from some snapshot server.

Your mirror is must a `mirrorOf` the central repository where I just assume your jar does not live but "in" the mirror.

My idea would be to set your mirror as a repository in your project's `pom.xml` like this

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>myInternalRepository</id>
    <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/???</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt see "**httpclient-starter:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT**" this jar in repo.spring.io.

1)
Try to open ***repo.spring.io*** on the browser. Then check the respective jar exising in that or not and also check your proxy settings in your settings.xml configuration.

https://repo.spring.io/snapshot

[Maven Proxy settings](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

[image]

2)
com.my.package:httpclient-starter:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT if exists then delete it manually from .m2 repository

3) mvn clean install.

4) Check your RepositoryId and Repository name as shown in pic.

[image]

Comment: No, `com.my.package:httpclient-starter:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` is exists in my mirror, which meas set mirror to `central` not work for me, `*` work for me but is not a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: Probably <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf> then name is wrong. verify name for the mirrorOf once again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264981/maven-repository-setting-xml-the-mirrorof  check this link. Probably it may help you.

Comment: @Karl.Li Check your RepositoryId and Repository name as shown in pic

Answer (score 0):

you can install the jar **httpclient-starter:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT** into you local maven repository with command maven install